# JQuery AJax Getting Page Fragments Find vs Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, find, jquery-filter

Here's the the form the Ajax code I am testing.

```
$('body').on('submit','#sign-in', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = $(this).serialize();

    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    $.ajax({
        //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
        url : url,
        type : "POST",
        data : data,
        dataType:"html",
        //Do not cache the page
        cache : false,
        //success
        success : function(response,status) {
            console.log($(response).filter('#dashboard'));
            console.log($(response).find('#dashboard').html());
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the response.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<body>
    <div id = "dashboard">
        <div id = "dash2">
        <h1>HELLO</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Based from the code above upon, success jQuery `filter` was able to fetch the div with an id `#dashboard` however `find` return me an `undefined`.

Why is it working like that?

For your information, I am using JQuery 1.9

**UPDATE**

Using the suggestion of Bergi, I have removed the html,body and head tag of the returned html and this is the error I received.

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>
> ## HELLO
>
> HELLO FITCCHHH
>               
>            jquery-1.9.0.min.js:2

Comment: `response` is a string, not a HTML document, isn't it?

Comment: I am not quite sure? but when I alert(response) it gives me the whole html layout/structure

Comment: Then it's a string, not a DOM object. You can easily check by logging it or using `typeof`.

Comment: I see, is there anyway I can translate that string to a DOM object?

Comment: append it to a hidden `<div>`

Comment: see possible duplicate [Parse complete html page with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429851/parse-complete-html-page-with-jquery)

Comment: @Bergi what is the reason why it did not work?

Comment: NB:after rereading your question i'm confused why sending back as response a full html document with doctype, header body ... you're making the request from a doc that already has header, body; so why is that ? deleting my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery sets your whole page as the `innerHTML` of a `<div>`, and therefore doctype, html, head and body elements are not parsed. You only get back a collection of the resulting elements, and since your `#dashboard` is one of these top-level elements you need to `filter` instead of `find`.

See also:

- [Parse complete html page with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429851/parse-complete-html-page-with-jquery)
- [Scrape an HTML Document with jQuery, is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3217632/1048572)

I'm not sure how to solve this, apparently there's much jQuery quirks around there. What I can think of:

- try [jQuery.parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)
- rely on `filter` getting the element in question out of the jQuery collection. Though, since browsers seem not to be consistent about what the parse you should do something like  `$response[$response.is("#dashboard") ? "filter" : "find"]("#dashboard")`
- Append the malformed collection to some element and `find` from there: `$("<div/>").html(response).find("#dashboard")`
- wait for [`jQuery.parseHTML`](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11617)
- do not send a whole HTML document, but only the `#dashboard` element you're interested in as a html string

Comment: Out of curiosity why would I use parseXML? and another thing, the dataType: "text/html", when I added to my ajax code, it stopped sending the request

Comment: The XML parser would respect the `<html>`, `<body>` etc tags. Though your html would need to be valid XHTML, of course. Oh, and you're right, [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) does not expect real MIME types

Comment: aww too bad, I am using HTML5

Comment: I've tried removing the head, html  and the body tag, but it gave me an Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <div id = "dashboard">
  <div id = "dash2">
  <h1>HELLO</h1>
  
  </div>
 </div>

Comment: And where did that Syntax Error happen? Afaik, syntax errors are for scripts and from malformed HTML you should get a Parse Error

Comment: On my debugger, I clicked that and this showed up jquery-1.9.0.min.js:2 thats where the error is coming from. I find it weird.

Comment: What's the stack trace? Was it a function call from you, or something internal to ajax?

Comment: That's strange, seems like it was treated as a script. What MIME type do you use?

Comment: on the server side? I did not specify any, but by default it returns an html.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jquery 1.9 , you should no-longer parse html like so:

```
var html = $(response);
```

Instead you should be using the following:

```
var html = $.parseHTML(response);
html = $(html).find('#dashboard').html();
```

**From Jquery Docs 1.9:**
*HTML strings passed to jQuery() that start with something other than a less-than character will be interpreted as a selector. Since the string usually cannot be interpreted as a selector, the most likely result will be an "invalid selector syntax" error thrown by the Sizzle selector engine. Use jQuery.parseHTML() to parse arbitrary HTML.*

Answer (score 1):

You should use parseHTML as indicated above.  The difference between filter and find appears to be where the element is in the returned HTML snippet.  If you are looking for #foo then use .filter('#foo') if #foo is a top-level element in the returned HTML and .find('#foo') otherwise.