# Update outer variable with jQuery each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm testing a simple script where I'm storing an html string into a variable, and want to replace a part of it. My actual code is a large html string, and I cannot use replace() in this case as I have wrap() and nextSibling() functions inside my each().

```
<script>
var htmlvar = "<html><head></head><body><p><i>test</i></p></body></html>";

htmlvar = $(htmlvar).find('i').each(function() {

          $(this).html('changed');

});

console.log('value: '+htmlvar[0].outerHTML);
</script>
```

After running the above the output is:

```
<i>changed</i>
```

I want to still have the full html tags after my each() function performs the logic on some of the tags. Is there any way to achieve this?

***EDIT:***

The same thing works with document object

```
<body>
<p><i>test</i>

<script>

    $(document).find('i').each(function() {

              $(this).wrap('<h1></h1>');

    });

    console.log('value: '+$(document).find('html').html());
    </script>

</body>
```

Output is full html of the current document.

Comment: `htmlvar` is a string. You can't alter it with jquery dom manipulation methods.

Comment: Are you going to have more than one `<i>` to change?

Comment: My actual html has lots of other tags. This is just a sample.

Comment: Moving `.find('i').each(function() {` to a new line that acts on `htmlvar` would probably solve your problem. but... i expect it to also remove all the html/body/head tags. If you want to keep them, you might have to re-think your approach.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kevin. Tried, and still losing other tags

Comment: Yes, because when you create an element in an existing dom that contains those tags, those tags get removed. That's just how it be. An alternative would be *not* doing that, but that's probably not a good idea.

Comment: The latter portion of your question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217632/scrape-an-html-document-with-jquery-is-it-possible/3218941#3218941 TLDR, jquery is useless in this case if you want to keep the html/body/head tags. At that point you're left with parsing the html with plain old string manipulation methods. goodluck with that

Comment: I have edited my question. It's working with document object. But not when I store an html in a variable. Any idea?

Comment: the document is a full document. That's an entirely different scenario and isn't going to help with your problem. Read the answer i linked to. The document isn't an html string that is being parsed.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your string to actual DOM nodes wrapped inside of a JQuery object, you then don't need `.find`. You can just search for the `i` element within the node (using the context argument to the JQuery selector) and change the text of it.

```js
var $htmlvar = $("<html><head></head><body><p><i>test</i></p></body></html>");
console.log($htmlvar[0].outerHTML);
$("i", $htmlvar).text('changed');
console.log($htmlvar[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: A down vote 3 seconds after posting?! For the right answer!

Comment: Thanks for the reply Scott. My actual code is not a text replacement. It's something like this: $(this.nextSibling).html($(this.nextSibling).wrap( "<div></div>"));  --My point to this question is, if each() function manipulates the found tag of the variable by keeping the other parts

Comment: I mean... the find existing or not existing is irrelevant to the problem. what fixed it was the other changes you made but didn't mention. `$("i", $htmlvar)` is still a `.find()`.

Answer (score -1):

Use `append()` instead of `html()`. It will, as the name suggests, append a given string instead of replacing an entire element.

`$(this).append('changed');`

Comment: With this change, the result would be `<i>testchanged</i>` or similar.